# Alter table, passing dataype by parameter, results in a syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Im using Visual Studio to create a program. In this program i have to look up for all the tables created and see if a column from a list exists, if not create it. To do that i created this variables:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> TABLE_DICT //the string saves the name of the table, the list the columns and types
List<Dictionary<string, string>> TABLE_LIST = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(); //list of columns in a table with its type
Dictionary<string, string> DICT = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // name of column and the type of this column
```

The code is the following:

```
try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + DBstring);
                conn.Open();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> TABLE_kvp in TABLE_DICT)
                {
                    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> dic in TABLE_kvp.Value)
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dic)
                        {
                            DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { null, null, TABLE_kvp.Key, kvp.Key });
                            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                                command.Connection = conn;
                                command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN ? ? ";
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", TABLE_kvp.Key);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", kvp.Key);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", kvp.Value);
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                command.Connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                ErrorForm ef = new ErrorForm(ex.Message, this.BackColor);
                ef.ShowDialog(this);
            }
```

The problem is that the code catch an exception for syntax error, even when i chanche the command text for the following stll does a syntax error:

```
command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN [?] ? NULL";
command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN [?] ?";
command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [?] ADD COLUMN ? ? ";
command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN ? MEMO ";
```

Searching in google, at least the last one of the list, do not have to make an error,or this is what i believe, but still does. Any idea?

Comment: >> `command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN ? ? ";` that is invalid commandtext

Comment: What type of database are you using? Did you try the raw sql in database first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL statements can't be parametrized.  You need to concatenate it in code.  And because you need to do it this way, you must either

- Validate the parameters, *or*
- Be absolutely sure your parameters are trusted.

Example code with validation:

```
var validator = new Regex(@"^\w+$");
if (new[] { TABLE_kvp.Key, kvp.Key, kvp.Value }.All(validator.IsMatch))
{
    command.CommandText = String.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD COLUMN {1} {2}", 
        TABLE_kvp.Key,
        kvp.Key,
        kvp.Value);   
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem, i didn't thought in concatenate the code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Bind variables/parameters are for values only, not for table names. You have to change the table names as part of your application logic.

On top of that you cannot run DDL commands using parameters. It is only meant for DML (INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE or invoking stored procedures)